# Expectation of maximum of K Erlang variables: Am I doing it right?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I want to find the expected value for the maximum of $K$ Erlang random variables (sum of two i.i.d exponential random variables with parameter $\gamma$), where $K = \frac{1}{\gamma}$. Below is what I have so far.

Let $$T = max(Z_1, Z_2, \cdots , Z_K)$$ where $Z_i$ is an Erlang random variable.
The CDF of each Erlang random variable is $$F(X) = 1 - (1 + \gamma\cdot x)\cdot e^{-\gamma\cdot x}$$
The CDF for the maximum is then $$F_T(t) = P(T \leq t) = P(Z_1 \leq t, Z_2 \leq t, \cdots , Z_K \leq t)$$
Because all random variables are i.i.d, $$F_T(t) = P(Z_1 \leq t)\cdot P(Z_2 \leq t)\cdot~\cdots~\cdot P(Z_k \leq t) = F(t)^K = (1 - (1 + \gamma\cdot t)\cdot e^{-\gamma\cdot t})^K$$
To find the expected value, I must first differentiate $F_T(t)$ to find $f_T(t)$ which comes out to be $$f_T(t) = \gamma\cdot t\cdot e^{-\gamma\cdot t}\cdot[1 - (1 + \gamma t)\cdot e^{-\gamma\cdot t}]^{k - 1}$$
The expected value is then $$E[T] = \int_0^\infty t\cdot f_T(t)~dt = \gamma\int_0^\infty t^2\cdot e^{-\gamma\cdot t}\cdot[1 - (1 + \gamma t)\cdot e^{-\gamma\cdot t}]^{k - 1}~dt$$
Using the code below in MATLAB for $K = 20$ for numerical computation,

```
K = 20;
g = 1/K; % gamma
upper_bound = 10000
average = g * quad(@(x) f(x, K, g), 0, upper_bound)

function ret = f(x, k, g)
    ret = (x.^2).*exp(-g.*x).*((1 - exp(-g.*x).*(1 + g.*x)).^(k - 1));
end
```

I get

```
average =

 4.020119085379661e-08
```

which is definitely incorrect. If I increase `upper_bound` to say `1000000`, the average drops to $0$. Using a different simulation for the same value of $K$, the average comes out to be `1.087141200000000e+02` which looks reasonable. What am I doing wrong in calculating the expected value, $E[T]$? The derivative of $F_T(t)$ seems to be fine.

Comment: Small comment, but in general, the parameter, $\gamma$, of an exponential RV is a positive real, so considering $K=\gamma^{-1}$ many RVs is less than meaningful... all is well if $\gamma$ is a unit fraction, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was caused by the `quad` function. The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quad.html) on this suggests to use the `integral` function instead. Once I switched `quad` with `integral`, I got the right answer. I am not sure if this is a bug.